# Return inside foreach inside shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, function, foreach, shortcode

I'm using the PHP code below to display CSS classes based on the custom taxonomies applied to my WordPress posts. My taxonomy is called CC and its three options are x, y, and z. For a post that has all three:

```
 $cc_terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,'cc');
 foreach ($cc_terms as $term) { 
     echo ' '.$term->slug.'-active'; 
 }
```

outputs: x-active y-active z-active

I'm trying to convert it into WordPress shortcode function (where `echo` doesn't work as far as I know) and basically I need to figure out how to capture `cc_class()` as one variable (not an array) so that it give me the same output as above.

```
function cc_meta($atts, $content = null) {
    global $post;
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('class' => 'default'), $atts));
    function cc_class() {
        $cc_terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'cc');
        foreach($cc_terms as $term) {
            return ' '.$term->slug.'-active';
        }
    }
    return '<div class="' . esc_attr($class) . cc_class() . '">...</div>';
}
```

outputs: `<div class="default x-active">...</div>`

It's only taking the first term rather than all three, which makes me wonder how `return` works in `foreach` loops. Any idea how I can get this to work?

desired output: `<div class="default x-active y-active z-active">...</div>`

**Update 1**: I tried with the `.=` as suggested and I'm getting a blank error:

```
function cc_meta( $atts, $content = null ) {
    global $post;
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('class' => 'default'), $atts));

    $cc_terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'cc');
    foreach ($cc_terms as $term) {
        $return .= ' '.$term->slug.'-active';
    }
    return '<div class="' . esc_attr($class) . $return . '">...</div>';
}
```

**Update 2**: I removed the `global $post` line and it works—sweet! Thanks everyone =)

```
function cc_meta($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('class' => 'default'), $atts));
    $cc_terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'cc');
    foreach($cc_terms as $term) { 
        $return .= ' '.$term->slug.'-active';
    }
    return '<div class="' . esc_attr($class) . $return . '">...</div>';
}
```

Comment: On a side-note, if you want more answers you should give feedback on the answers to the questions you already asked. [See the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how this community operates.

Comment: @stefgosselin I had tried that before but it said I didn't have a high enough reputation to rate answers yet but I guess I do now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't return in the middle of your function, use return only at the end.

Instead of `return` use this:

```
$return .=
```

and before the closing `}` do a `return $return;`

Comment: @powtac @ibu Thanks good call. That seems like it should work but I'm get a blank error now with the updated function - please see UPDATE in the question above.

Comment: @ryanve: Make sure to define `$return` before you add to it. Add `$return = '';` before the loop and **turn on [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)**!

Comment: @wesley-murch Thanks / I removed `global $post` line and it works with or w/o `$return = '';` before the loop. Thanks for the tip about the error reporting!

Comment: Not defining $return, would "only" throw a Notice not a Warning... But it is always recommended to avoid Notices!